# Does anyone have an Emacs macro for indenting (and unindenting) blocks of text?

Tags: emacs, lisp, elisp

Does anyone have an Emacs macro for indenting (and unindenting) blocks of text?

And I mean "indent" in the commonly-understood sense, not in Emacspeak. In other words, I want to mark a region, press C-u 2, run this macro, and have it add two spaces before every line in the region.

Or press C-u -2 before running the macro and have it *remove* two spaces from the start of each line in the region. Bonus points if it complains if the lines don't have enough leading whitespace.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/594156/using-emacs-to-indent-shift-4-code/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

indent-rigidly (bound to C-x TAB) does what you want.  It's in indent.el, which should be part of the standard emacs distribution.

Also, to have it complain/abort when there's not enough whitespace somewhere, you can do something like this:  (quick ugly hack of the original indent-rigidly code)

```
(defun enough-whitespace-to-indent-p (start end arg)
  (save-excursion
    (goto-char end)
    (setq end (point-marker))
    (goto-char start)
    (or (bolp) (forward-line 1))
    (while (and (< (point) end)
                (>= (+ (current-indentation) arg) 0))
      (forward-line 1))
    (>= (point) end)))

(defun indent-rigidly-and-be-picky (start end arg)
  (interactive "r\np")
  (if (or (plusp arg) (enough-whitespace-to-indent-p start end arg))
      (indent-rigidly start end arg)
(message "Not enough whitespace to unindent!")))
```

Answer (score 3):

Can also use the world of [rectangles](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Rectangles.html#Rectangles).
To insert two spaces:

```
C-x r t SPC SPC RET
```

Deleting two spaces is

```
C-x r d
```

provided that you've defined the rectangle to cover two spaces.  There's also a nice addition to rectangle editing in the CUA package.  The CUA package covers more than just rectangles, so if you just want the rectangle portion, check out [this description](http://trey-jackson.blogspot.com/2008/10/emacs-tip-26-cua-mode-specifically.html) (full disclosure, link is to my blog).

Answer (score 2):

Use `indent-rigidly` bound by default to `C-x TAB`