# Shift a region or line in emacs

Tags: emacs, indentation, text-manipulation

I'm looking for a way in emacs to shift text to the right or to the left by `n` spaces. A similar functionality that it in vim `<<` or `>>`. It should work on a region or if no region is selected on a current line and not move the cursor from its current location.

The solution from [EmacsWiki](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/IndentingText) does not work very well as the `M-x indent-rigidly` since it somewhat remembers the last region used and shifts that one instead. The closest seems to be the one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/594156/using-emacs-to-indent-shift-4-code) but I did not managed to make it work. I'm not a lisp developer so it's difficult to modify the code. I will appreciate any help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Maybe this works the way you want.

```
(defun shift-text (distance)
  (if (use-region-p)
      (let ((mark (mark)))
        (save-excursion
          (indent-rigidly (region-beginning)
                          (region-end)
                          distance)
          (push-mark mark t t)
          (setq deactivate-mark nil)))
    (indent-rigidly (line-beginning-position)
                    (line-end-position)
                    distance)))

(defun shift-right (count)
  (interactive "p")
  (shift-text count))

(defun shift-left (count)
  (interactive "p")
  (shift-text (- count)))
```

Comment: Excellent! That is exactly what I was looking for! Thanks a lot. Don't you wanna put it also to EmacsWiki?

Comment: What should I do to make it shift `4` call the function 4 times?

Answer (score 40):

You could select the region then `C-u C-x <tab>` will shift 4 spaces. You can type a number after C-u to change 4 to anything else.

Comment: One more tip: the number after `C-u` may be negative, in this case region will be shifted to the left instead of to the right.

Answer (score 6):

To achieve this I usually do a trick:

- activate CUA mode
- go to the beginning of line
- C-RET, now if you move the cursor you should see a *rectangular* red region
- Move the cursor down the lines and type space until you've obtained the correct shifting.

This can be done also programmatically in some way (in the same way).

EDIT:
I've just read the article in emacs wiki, it's the same solution except for the CUA mode that is infinitely more powerful than the "common" rectanguar selection (since it's visual).

Comment: You can enable CUA's excellent rectangle editing facilities separately from its other features with `(cua-selection-mode t)`. Provided you don't have `C-RET` bound to something else, you can put this in your init file and it won't conflict with anything.

Comment: Quick notes on basic usage for shifting lines: `C-RET` + cursor movements to specify rectangle, `RET` to cycle corners, typing inserts before/after rectangle, `C-RET` to exit. See the notes under "CUA rectangle support" in cua-base.el for the full details on what this minor mode provides, or read http://trey-jackson.blogspot.com/2008/10/emacs-tip-26-cua-mode-specifically.html

Comment: I have a confession. I use CUA mode.

Comment: LOVE THIS TIP (emacs user of 20+ years)

Answer (score 0):

As I use [Evil](https://github.com/emacs-evil/evil) (with [Spacemacs](https://www.spacemacs.org/)), the Vim-like region shifting is already implemented in visual mode with <kbd>S-v</kbd> and <kbd><</kbd>/<kbd>></kbd> properly.

I'm mostly using `hybrid-mode` though, and when it's active I also want to be able to shift the region, preferrably by the current language's `shift-width`.

To achieve this, here's an implementation that re-uses evil's shifting, but does it "properly" in `hybrid-mode`.

```lisp
(defun jj/shift-text (beg end shift-block-fun shift-line-fun)
  "shift text in region or line using evil like S-v with < and > do in Vim.
  It takes special care of preserving or even extending the region to the moved text lines."
  (if (use-region-p)
      (progn
        (let ((point-at-end (< (mark) (point))))

          ;; fix up current region end to grab the whole line
          (if point-at-end
              (end-of-line)
            (beginning-of-line))

          ;; then fix up the other region end
          (exchange-point-and-mark)
          (if point-at-end
              (beginning-of-line)
            (end-of-line))

          ;; restore mark-point order
          (exchange-point-and-mark)

          (let ((linebeg (if point-at-end (mark) (point)))
                (lineend (if point-at-end (point) (mark))))
            ;; shift the text
            (save-mark-and-excursion
              (funcall shift-block-fun linebeg lineend)
              ;; "In Transient Mark mode, every buffer-modifying primitive sets deactivate-mark"
              ;; but we wanna keep it active :)
              (setq deactivate-mark nil)))))

    (funcall shift-line-fun 1)))

(defun jj/shift-left (beg end)
  (interactive "r")
  (jj/shift-text beg end #'evil-shift-left #'evil-shift-left-line))

(defun jj/shift-right (beg end)
  (interactive "r")
  (jj/shift-text beg end #'evil-shift-right #'evil-shift-right-line))
```

and where your keybindings are defined:

```lisp
  ;; text shifting. evil-normal-state-map has these anyway.
  (define-key evil-hybrid-state-map (kbd "M-<") #'jj/shift-left)
  (define-key evil-hybrid-state-map (kbd "M->") #'jj/shift-right)
```